# What does the noeol indicator at the bottom of a vim edit session mean?

Tags: vim

I opened a file using `vim` on Ubuntu, and the following is displayed at the bottom of the screen:

```
"file.py" [noeol] 553L, 16620C
```

What does `noeol` indicate?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263869/does-vi-silently-add-a-newline-lf-at-the-end-of-file

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31947/100397

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unix editors like `vi` and `vim` will always put newlines (`\n`) at the end of every line - especially including the last line. If there is no end-of-line (`eol`) on the last line, then it is an unusual situation and the file most certainly was not created by a standard UNIX editor.

This unusual situation is brought to your notice by the `[noeol]` flag in the `vim` editor; other editors probably have similar flags and notifications.

Answer (score 23):

That the last line in the file doesn't have a newline (\n)

Comment: *@Bon Ami:* Some programs, when reading your text file, need the `\n` at the end of line to consider it as a completed line (with a trailing newline char).  The following example shows a file which may look like a **complete** line at a casual glance in a text editor, but `wc` does **not** condider it as a line: `printf "x">"file-no-newline"; wc -l <"file-no-newline"` -- Outpute is:  `0`  .. the **noeol** is just a visual aid to let you know the status..

Answer (score 3):

This means the OS where you viewing the file is not able to detect the line-ending of the file (if the file has any at all). Sometimes this happenes when you move file(s) across OSes(i,e.. from MS to *nix os)

In vim, if the file has windows carriage return "`^M"`, you can fix it with the following command in vim:

```
:%s/^M/\r/g
```

meaning:

```
%      => select the whole buffer
s      => substitute
/^M/   => find Windows carriage return.
/\r/   => replace it with *nix carriage return
```

Note: in Mac OX, `^M is ctl+v  &&  ctrl+m`

Answer (score -5):

Its **'NO EOL' - no end of line** indicator. Very helpful if you end up opening a very large file (>1GB). Vim tries to pull all that in 1 line. This indicator helps me quickly close the file before it screws up my OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's not what this flag means...